# Any honeypot available to run webservice

Tags: honeypot

I'm new to honeypots. I wanted to know if there are any honeypot platform for hosting my own webservice? I came across glasstopf but I read that it emulates its own web app.

Comment: What are you expecting the honeypot to do?

Comment: I just want it to show me the log files,Like i have a shopping cart webservice which is already vulnerable to few attacks,I expect it to be attacked,so i need the honeypot to show me the attacker activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honeypots run their own services because they are trying to capture specific information and they can only reliably capture that data if they control the service.

If you want to run your own "honeypot" with your own service, then why not just run your own service?

1. Place the disposable service on a dedicated server that is segregated from your live environments
2. Put in protections so that if the server gets taken over that it cannot harm others (like an external firewall that blocks all outgoing connections)
3. Set up centralised logging and alerting on what you are looking for
4. Configure the server to rebuild nightly

With VMs, containers, and hosted virtual servers, this can be set up very simply.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be to review the 'state-of-the-art' in honey pots, one of the very first projects that has helped promote the concept is [HoneyD](http://www.honeyd.org/).

Since then there have been plenty of variations on the theme, some of my favourite are written in Python, such as [OpenCanary](http://docs.opencanary.org/en/latest/).

So, the short answer is yes, there are but you do need to [DYOR](https://github.com/paralax/awesome-honeypots) (see Service Honeypots) in order to find the one that best suits your needs.